# Need input on a dynamic query output script

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a homepage that has a bunch of images as links to other pages that has info about that image.

```
Image Name: $varExampleNAME
Damage: $varExampleDMG
Health: $varExampleHP
Mana: $varExampleMP
```

So the only info that will change on this page will be the variables.
What I want is to run one query script so that depending on the $fileName of the $currentPage
it grabs that row from the table if the $fileName matches a certain row name.

This is the script to find out what my fileName is:

```
//include database connection file
include_once 'connect_to_db.php';

$currentFile = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
$img = array_pop(explode("/", $currentFile));
$fileName$ = basename($img, ".php").PHP_EOL;
```

I'm having problems with the actual query script. Can anyone shed some light on how this will be done?

My table name is image_Name

Columns include id, name, damage, health, mana.

Comment: I think you might be confusing rows and columns in the last sentence.

Comment: Edited to fix rows/columns typo

Answer (score 0):

You should design your tables in order to fit your needs, in this case to retrieve a row based on a parameter.

If the `name` field of the table is consistent with the script filenames, you should do [using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)]:

```
// Create a connection handler - provide your credentials
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourDbNane','username','password');

// Prepare the query with a placeholder
$dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM image_Name WHERE name = ?');

// Fill the placeholder with the filename
$dbh->execute( array($fileName) );

// Fetch the result, you are done!
$img = $dbh->fetch();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm sure this works, but I'm still kind of new with php and unsure how to format your script properly. What info will need to be changed for it to work with my database?

Comment: You just have to replace `yourDbNane` with the name of your db, then provide your MySQL server username and password [arguably `root` and `''`. In order to learn, you have to try and fail till you get it done, be brave!

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute() in C:\xampp\htdocs\series\****.tv\****.php on line 18 .......


this is the fatal error i'm getting. Hey thanks for the help too

Comment: $currentFile = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
 $img = array_pop(explode("/", $currentFile));
 $fileName = basename($img, ".php").PHP_EOL;
 //echo $fileName;


    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase","user","");

    $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM image_Name WHERE name = ?');

    $dbh->execute( array($fileName) );

    $img = $dbh->fetch();

    echo $img;

Comment: I fixed the fatal error by adding $st = $dbh->prepare and then doing $st->execute... but getting no echo returned